# ActiveModelをActiveRecord::Relationのように複数(collection)にして参照したい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

ホテルの予約システムを実装しており、
予約情報が格納された`Reservation`と
その予約情報を元に予約状況を参照するための`ReservedState`を定義してます。

```
  # 予約テーブル
  class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ~略~ 部屋idや 予約開始(終了)時刻等が定義されている

    scope :reservable, -> (time = Time.current) {
      where(arel_table[:started_at].lteq(time))
          .where(arel_table[:ended_at].gteq(time.advance(minutes: 60))) 
      # TODO: 60min以外でも検知出来るようにする
    }

    # 予約可能か
    def self.reservable?(time)
      reservable(time).empty?
    end

    def self.create_day_hash(day = Time.current)
      hash = {}
      hash[:dated_at] = day
      0.upto(24) do |hour|
        # ex) hash[:hour00] = true
        hash['hour' + hour.to_s.rjust(2, '0')] = reservable?(day.change(hour: hour))
      end
      hash
    end
  end

  # 予約情報モデル
  class ReservedState
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_accessor :dated_at, 
      # その他 予約時間を参照するためのBooleanカラム :hour00 ~ :hour23 

    def initialize(attributes={})
      super
    end
  end
```

## index.html.slim

```
  table
    thead
      tr
        th 時間
        th = @reserved_state.dated_at
        / 本当は - @reserved_states.each do |r| でCollection回したい
    tbody
      - 0.upto(23).each do |x|
        tr
          td = "#{x.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:00"
          td = @reserved_state.special_hour(x.to_s.rjust(2, '0'))

  # ~ 略 ~

  class ReservedStateDecorator < Draper::Decorator
    delegate_all

    def special_hour(hour)
      object.send("hour#{hour}") ? '○' : '×'
    end
  end
```

予約状況(空き状況)を調べるためには下記内容で出力できています。
`ReservationsController`

```
  @reserved_state = ReservedState.new(Reservation.create_day_hash)
```

ただし、`ReservedState`は`ActiveModel::Model`であり
`ActiveRecord::Relation`のように複数の予約情報を保持しておくことが出来ません。
(ページネーションしたい)

- [選択肢1] `ActiveModel::Model`で複数のデータが入るようにする。
- [選択肢2] `ActiveRecord::Base`を継承したモデルを作り、それ用のテーブルも作る

この場合、どのような実装にすれば良いでしょうか。

Comment: `@reserved_state`はViewの中でどのように使われるのでしょうか？できればViewのコードも追記してください。「複数の予約情報を保持しておくことが出来ません」とありますが、`Reservation.create_day_hash`はhashとして複数の情報を保持しているように僕には見えます。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。viewを追記しました。
`@reserved_state`は各時間(0~23時)の予約情報を取得しておりますが
[複数日]の予約情報を持てずに困っております。ex) `@reserved_states`の中身には今日の日付(`dated_at`)とその予約状況(`hour00~23`)を保持しておき 次のrecordを見ると明日の日付情報を参照できるようにする。

Comment: Viewのコードがまだ追記されていないようです。確認をお願いします。

Comment: 追加しました! 確認お願いします!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「本当は - @reserved_states.each do |r| でCollection回したい」とありますが、単純にコントローラーの中でReservedStateを複数作って配列にすればよいのでは？と思いました。

```
# Controller
def index
  # 今日から7日先までの予約データを集める
  @reserved_states = 7.times.map {|n|
    ReservedState.new(Reservation.create_day_hash(Time.current.since(n.days))) 
  }
end
```

「いやいや、それだとダメなんです」という場合はもう少し詳しくやりたいことを追記してください。

Comment: そもそも複数の情報を保持する=`ActiveRecord_Relation`みたいなイメージがありそれじゃないとページネーションは使えないと勝手に思い込んでました。。 確かにJunichiさんのように配列にしてそれをviewで使えば問題なく解決できますね!! 本当にいつも助かっております。ありがとうございます!!